# Clickable text in /tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here's the command:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[HINT]","color":"dark_green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @p {\"text\":\"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"]"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}}]
```

That brings up `[HINT]`, which is bold and dark green, and when you hover over it, it says "*Click For Hint*". The problem is that when you click it, it should activate a `tellraw` command, however when I click it, I get:

```
Invalid json: Unterminated object at line 1 column 81
```

This JSON is flawless (or so I thought). What is wrong?

Comment: You're missing a `}` near the end, and your first `[` doesn't seem to match up.  It's easy to see in a coding text editor like Notepad++.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm not quite seeing it. If you could leave an answer with the incorrect syntax bolded, I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was an idiot, and made 1 small mistake that changed everything. Here was the full command:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This map is based off of 1.9 features such as detecting when you pick up items,","color":"green"},{"text":" [HINT] ","color":"dark_green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @p {\"text\":\"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"}"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}},{"text":"so you may need to think outside of the box for some levels. good Luck!","color":"green"}]
```

If you will notice, light_purple had a ] after it instead of }. My bad...

Comment: Can you accept this answer?

Comment: @kit done, sorry I didn't get to this sooner, the question was very dead

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out! try this:

```
/tellraw @p [{"text":"[HINT]","color":"dark_green","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @p [{\"text\":\"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"}]"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}}]
```

the true in `bold:true` was missing the quotes, I had to remove one "}" at the very end because there was one too many and I took out the two quotes at the beginning because they didn't seem like they would do anything. I also switched some of the "}" and "]" in the tellraw command containing the hint.

Comment: The OP has already answered the question themselves. It doesn't seem helpful to provide another answer that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is missing some brackets and braces.  Try this instead:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[HINT]","color":"dark_green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @p {[\"text\":\"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"]"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}}}]
```

I can't verify that it'll do exactly what you want, but I'm fairly certain I've fixed the syntax error.

Comment: [23:41:06] Invalid json: Unterminated array at line 1 column 298